# Accessing a JSON element inside JSON

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am getting data stored in MySQL database from a PHP script using jQuery ajax. I am parsing the data returned in JSON format and displaying it in a table.

The problem is one of the element is stored in json format so MySQL returns the entire data and it is displayed in the same manner.

```
$.each(data, function (key, element) {
    $('table').append('<tr><td>' + element.aid + '</td><td>' + element.userid + '</td><td>' + element.atitle + '</td><td>' + element.atype +  '</td><td>' + element.adata + '</td></tr>');  
});
```

element.adata is being displayed in the following manner :

```
{
    "click_title":"GO",
    "links": {
        "commonlink":"http:\/\/bookings.com",
        "alllinks": [
            [{
            "link1":"http:\/\/xyz1.com\/get\/a",
            "link2":"http:\/\/www.anotherwebsite1.com\/c\/t",
            "link3":"http:\/\/www.newsite1.com\/v\/h"
            },{
            "link1":"http:\/\/xyz2.com\/get\/a",
            "link2":"http:\/\/www.anotherwebsite2.com\/c\/t",
            "link3":"http:\/\/www.newsite2.com\/v\/h"
         }],[{
            "link1":"http:\/\/xyz3.com\/get\/a",
            "link2":"http:\/\/www.anotherwebsite3.com\/c\/t",
            "link3":"http:\/\/www.newsite3.com\/v\/h"
         }]
        ]
    }
}
```

How do I access the links so that I can display them in a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could parse the JSON string to a javascript object using the [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) function:

```
var data = $.parseJSON(element.adata);
```

and then access individual elements. For example:

```
data.links[0][0].link1
```

or if you don't know the number of elements in advance you could also loop through them using $.each.

Comment: can I do this inside <td></td>, like currently I am displaying element.adata in a table - '</td><td>' + element.adata + '</td></tr>'

Comment: Yes, you can. The first step is to parse the JSON string to a javascript variable using the $.parseJSON function. Then depending on what and how you want to display it, you could access directly the elements of the resulting object.

Comment: it says data is null in firebug

Comment: Is `element.adata` a valid JSON string?

Comment: yes, as I have shown above, that exactly the way it is displayed

Comment: I am not asking how is it displayed but what underlying type is it. Is it a valid JSON string? If it is then `$.parseJSON(element.adata);` will return a javascript object that you could use. If it isn't a string I have to know what exactly it is in order to be able to help you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27226/discussion-between-stacy-j-and-darin-dimitrov)